# PRNG library which support store/restore sequencing state?

Tags: c++, c

I am writing some functional style code which needs random number. State mutations are represented as stream(sequence) of state. This is designed for reproducibility. By storing each state, I expect I can continue mutation from at any state.

But the problem is random numbers. It is depending on some internal state, so just storing last number doesn't give me correct result. I need to store the PRNG state.

Is there any PRNG library which support store and restore of sequencing state? I wish to get a library with high quality of distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any PRNG library which support store and restore of sequencing state?

All good PRNG libraries allow you to store and restore their state.